# How to adjust opacity in Mapbox choropleth plot?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In Mapbox choropleth plots, is it possible to have no shade (i.e., transparent) if the value is less than a threshold? For example, for a variable ranging between 0 to 1, if the value is less than 0.05 don't show any shade.

```
    map.addLayer({
    'id': 'id_of_layer',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'source_name', // reference the data source
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': [
            'interpolate',
            ['linear'],
            ['get', 'field_name_in_json'],
            0.0, '#ffffff', 0.1, '#fee5d9', 0.3, '#fcbba1', 0.5, '#fc9272', 0.7, '#fb6a4a', 0.8, '#ef3b2c', 0.9, '#cb181d', 1.0, '#99000d'],
        'fill-opacity': 0.7
    }
});
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189201/is-there-a-color-code-for-transparent-in-html/18189313) I understood that Hex code for full transparency is #ffffff00. Following this, I modified my code above to: `0.0, '#ffffff00', 0.05, '#ffffff', 0.1, '#eff3ff', 0.3, '#c6dbef', 0.5, '#9ecae1', 0.7, '#6baed6', 0.8, '#4292c6', 0.9, '#2171b5', 1.0, '#084594'` Now Mapbox is not even rendering any plot.

How can I set a shape transparent if the value is less than a threshold?

Comment: You want to `filter` them instead, to actually not (attempt to) render them at all. To set it's opacity, either set `opacity` accodingly (if possible), or pass in `rgba()` values.